# PyInstaller Executable File: ModuleNotFoundError - Pandas

Tags: pandas, windows, pyinstaller, executable, modulenotfounderror

**Background:** I have a `.py` script which uses c.10 libraries/dependencies (e.g., `pandas` `numpy` `json`) and the script also relies on a `.ini` file, which it looks for in the same dir as it is located.
I want to add this `.py` file to Windows Scheduler, but before I can, I must make the file executable.

**Issue:** I used `PyInstaller` to create an executable file. I also added `-- onefile` and `-w` when creating the `.exe` file. My issue is that when I attempt to run the `main.exe` (either by double-clicking or through `cmd`) I get the following `Unhandled exception in script` -

[image]

**Help:** I am trying to understand how this is happening, especially as my understanding of `PyInstaller` is that it would create an executable file, which would inc. everything the script needs to run (Note: I have double checked that the `.py` contains `import pandas` etc.

Can someone explain to me how I would troubleshoot this and/or if there are any key steps I may have obviously missed, which might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this commandline for compiling your python file, `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --noconsole --hidden-import pandas  {Your_FILE_NAME}.py`